# pivot page in windows phone 8 LoadedPivot event not firing?

Tags: c#, silverlight, events, windows-phone-8, pivotitem

i just started with generic forms for windows phone 8 development.
No i want to test if a certain pivotitem is selected, then it should fire a function to load a  grid into that pivot item.

here is my xaml and my code so far
 XAML:

```
 <phone:Pivot Name="mainpivot" Title="MY APPLICATION" LoadingPivotItem="mainpivot_LoadingPivotItem" LoadedPivotItem="mainpivot_LoadedPivotItem_1">
        <!--Pivot item one-->
        <phone:PivotItem Name="staticpivot" Header="static">
            <!--Double line list with text wrapping-->
            <Grid Name="staticGrid" >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>



                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBox Name="txtUsername" Grid.Column="1" Height="70"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Name="txtPassword" Grid.Row="1" Height="70" Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Name="txtdescription" Grid.Row="2" Height="150"  Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBox>


                <TextBlock Height="40" Text="USERNAME" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Height="40" Text="PASSWORD" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Height="40" Text="DESCRIPTION" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2"></TextBlock>

                <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Tap="Button_Tap">SAVE DATA</Button>
            </Grid>
        </phone:PivotItem>

        <!--Pivot item two-->
        <phone:PivotItem x:Name="genericpivot" Header="generic">
            <!--Double line list no text wrapping-->
        </phone:PivotItem>
    </phone:Pivot>
```

as you can see the 2nd pivot has nothing in it, i am going to populate it dynamically with controls.

the problem is here in the code :

```
        private void mainpivot_LoadedPivotItem_1(object sender, PivotItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.Name == "genericpivot")
        {
            loadDetailForPivot();
        }
    }
```

this function does not fire when i debug and put a breakpoint there.
can anyone tell my why? or give a link that explains it.

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify, are you trying to populate the selected pivot item once it's selected?

I believe what you are after is picking up a change to the pivot controls selectedindex, such as (VB.net, sorry):

```
  Private Sub PivotItem_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles PivotItem.SelectionChanged
       If PivotItem.SelectedIndex = 1 Then LoadDetailForPivot
End Sub
```

However...why do you not load the controls beforehand? Wouldn't that be quicker (i.e. no delay while things are loaded as the user pivots). I did this on a previous app and the pivoting was jerky as a result.

Comment: @pumpkinzwan Thank for quick reply... you see the thing is, our current mobile app as it is, we load the control beforehand and everything works fine, but now with the new release we planning, the companys wont have same structure as  us, so we must make the control load as we recieve it from webservice? if that makes sense?...  and thanks! the event fires now :)